# ionic3 open external url without address bar and toolbar and close button

Tags: authentication, webview, inappbrowser, ionic3, external-url

My app needs a login page from external url.

The login logic that I thought is :

Steps

1. Open external url when ionic is launched
2. Once user logged in, move back to internal app using deep link (ex : myapp://main)

I tested step 2 which is deep link. Works well.

So, I have to make step 1 now.

First, I tested with `iframe`.
And got `Refused to display 'https:....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` error. Seems this needs a server-side configuration. But anyway we don't want to use this way. `iframe` feels like a hack.

Second, I tried `location.href = this.loginUrl;`.
Worked well in chrome browser but when I built in iOS simulator, **I see address bar, tool bar, and close button.**
I don't like this because I don't want user to close login page or to change url address.

Third, tried `window.open(this.loginUrl, '_self', 'location=no')`.
Same result as second.

Fourth, tried to use ionic version of `in-app-browser`[plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/).
But the result is same as second and third.
It still opens a browser with address bar, tool bar even it shows 'back to myApp'. So user would feel this is out of app.
[Check here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-all-links-in-app-browser/66442/24), people are looking for the solution still.

After spending a day, I don't even know if there is option I can try.

Comment: you can try `toolbar=no`  see IOS options at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve by doing this. But in real device.
Xcode iPhone emulators don't have open in-app-browser but built-in browser.

```
browser:any;

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.browser = this.iab.create(this.loginUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no'); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by installing a cordova plugin called cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. Execute the following commands:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

On your app.module.ts add

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
```

and also add the following to your providers in app.module.ts

```
    providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

Then on your home.ts add

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
```

and inject it into the constructor like this

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private iab: InAppBrowser) {

  }
```

then add the following method

```
 ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.iab.create('url', '_self', { location: 'no' }); }
```

Check the different options you have for this plugin [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

For removing the address bar just use the option:

```
location: Set to yes or no to turn the InAppBrowser's location bar on or off.
```

Comment: hey, I set location: 'no' then it hide address bar, but page navigation is not working. I have WordPress site.